# serialize function for string values to use in jQuery ajax datastring

Tags: php, jquery, string, serialization

how to sanitize user inputs that you gather by jquery .val() so you can write it in a dataString... in the example you see below when user writes

> if some text that contains & the rest
>   of the comment doesn't seem to work
>   fine because it counts the rest as an
>   other variable to POST..

is there a sanitaziation or
serialization code? jQuery's
sanitize() function works on forms but
i want something that i can use
directly use on strings...

```
var id = $("some_id_value_holder_hidden_field").val();
var comment = $("#sometextarea").val();

var dataString = "id=" + id + "&comment=" + comment;

$.ajax({

type: "POST",
url: "write_comment.php",
data: dataString,
dataType: "json",
success: function(res) {
  // Success
},
error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  // Error
}
});
```

Any suggestion will be much appreciated
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a built-in [encodeUriComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent) that does exactly what you're looking for. Besides that, you can provide an object in "data" field, in which case url encoding will be handled by jquery. In your example:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "write_comment.php",
     data: { id: id, comment: comment},
     etc...
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using jquery, you can use the included Form plugin to serialize the array.

serialize() - Creates a url string from form fields (eg, someEle=someVal&anotherEle=anotherVal)

serializeArray() - Returns a key/value array of all the form elements (useful to know)

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'write_comment.php',
    type : 'post',
    data : $('#form-element').serialize(),
    success : function(data)
    {
        alert('yay!');
    }
});
```

Edit: Edited to remove incorrect escape() part.

Comment: i could not make it work with textareas and input fields. i think serialize function can only be applied to form tag...

i have just a text area with no form tag around it so i need a function to serialize string not the whole form